# File handling in python for large amount of data

Tags: python, file-io

I am looking for some efficient way to read from a large file and grep a string `'abracadabra'` (=`s1`),
here `s1` is always present before eof(end of file)
And if `s1` is present search for another string `'P QRST'`

i.e. Data of File `f1`:

```
ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP
QRST UVW XY Z
...
...
abracadabra(eof)
```

I am novice for python, to do this I was using following method:

```
f = open('f1', 'r')
for line in f:
   if 'abracadabra' in line:
      print 'Found'
      found = True
      break
else:
   print 'EOF reached, string not found'        
f.close()

f = open('f1', 'r')
for line in f:
   if 'P QRST' in line:             # 'P QRST' can be present anywhere in the file(can be either in begging or just before s1)
      #do some operation
```

But this approach involves huge overhead for a large file data, as it read the files twice. Please suggest some efficient approach to do this.

Is there any efficient way like a **'grep'** application in Linux shell?

Comment: Why not search for both? You are already processing the file line by line, remembering if you've seen `'P QRST'` while also looking for `abracadabra` isn't an arduous task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find the abracadabra, set a flag, if you find the PQRST, set a flag, if you've found both, do something.

```
found = False
foundPQRST = False
f = open('f1', 'r')
for line in f:
   if 'P QRST' in line:
      foundPQRST= True
      PQRSTline = line   
   if 'abracadabra' in line:
      print 'Found'
      abraline = line
      found = True
   if found and foundPQRST:
      dosomething(PQRSTline, abraline)
      break
if not found:
   print "wasn't found"
f.close()
```

If there are multiple PQRST-matching lines, this will call `dosomething` with the last one before 'abracadabra' or the first one after. Not how it saves the PQRST line and the abracadabra line when it finds matches to use it in the call. You might not need to do this, depending on what `dosomething` does.

Also, you might want to use a `with` clause with the `open` function.

Comment: This can be possible but what if I can directly check for 'abracadabra'( because if s1 is present then it is just placed before eof)
# so if I can seek the file pointer to `pos=(total_size-sizeof(s1))` position then after reading sizeof(s1) bytes from `pos`, I can move the pointer at the s
tart of the file then readling line by lines and searing for 'P QRST', In C, this can be done through fseek, Is there any efficient way of doing this in python ?

Comment: I don't see the asymmetry between the two things you are looking for. You only do_something if you find both. So scan the file ONCE, looking for both, and doing your do_something AS SOON AS you find the second one of the two things. That's what my code does. Python does have "seek" and "tell" methods for files but without knowing more about your specific task you may not need them: https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html

Answer (score 2):

If `grep` already does what you want, then just use it with the `subprocess` module;

```
rv = subprocess.check_call(['grep', first, filename])
if rv is 0:
    rv = subprocess.check_call(['grep', second, filename])
    if rv is 0:
        print 'Found', second
    elif rv is 1:
        print second, 'not found'
    else:
        print 'Error looking for', second
elif rv is 1:
    print first, 'not found'
else:
    print 'Error looking for', first
```

**Edit:** (in response to comments)

Remember that the most efficient code is the one you *don't* have to write, since programmer time is much more expensive than computer time. Also keep in mind that `grep` has been [well optimized](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html). One of the big wins was not splitting the input into lines. Which your Python solution is doing twice.

At the very least you should keep the list of lines and re-use it.

But if you want to do it in Python, there are some things that you can copy from GNU `grep`;

- Use page-aligned, page-sized blocks of memory
- Avoid splitting the data into lines
- Use [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/mmap.html)

**Edit 2:**

As Spacedman correctly mentions, there is no substitute for testing. So let's do that.

I ran some tests on a 40 MB test file, searching for the non-existant string `abracadabra`. First, using BSD grep;

```
> time grep abracadabra procmail.log
0.242u 0.015s 0:00.25 100.0%    58+179k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time grep abracadabra procmail.log
0.192u 0.016s 0:00.20 100.0%    57+176k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time grep abracadabra procmail.log
0.184u 0.023s 0:00.20 100.0%    59+183k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time grep abracadabra procmail.log
0.199u 0.007s 0:00.20 95.0% 60+186k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time grep abracadabra procmail.log
0.184u 0.023s 0:00.20 100.0%    59+183k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time grep abracadabra procmail.log
0.184u 0.024s 0:00.20 100.0%    57+176k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

Then with the following program:

```
import mmap

with open('procmail.log', 'r+b') as p:
    mm = mmap.mmap(p.fileno(), 0)
    rv = mm.find('abracadabra')
    print rv
```

This gave:

```
> time python foo.py
-1
0.139u 0.024s 0:00.16 93.7% 1701+549k 0+1io 0pf+0w
> time python foo.py
-1
0.094u 0.039s 0:00.13 92.3% 1807+583k 0+1io 0pf+0w
> time python foo.py
-1
0.109u 0.023s 0:00.13 92.3% 1807+583k 0+1io 0pf+0w
> time python foo.py
-1
0.117u 0.015s 0:00.13 92.3% 1807+583k 0+1io 0pf+0w
> time python foo.py
-1
0.125u 0.007s 0:00.13 92.3% 1807+583k 0+1io 0pf+0w
```

So;

- on my machine
- searching for a simple string

using `mmap` in Python is slightly faster than calling BSD `grep`.

Keep in mind that the `mmap` objects (at least in python 2.7) do not support searching for regular expressions. And results may differ with file size, size of the RAM, operating system et cetera.

Comment: Yes, this can also be possible. Which approach is more efficient, in terms of memory utilization and time consumption ? As far as I know grep uses regex, so searching is much faster, but I don't have idea about the memory consumption using grep and using python file handling.

Comment: grep works line by line, so doesn't chew up memory. But then reading a file in python line by line doesn't chew up memory either. But running grep TWICE could be slower than scanning it once in Python, depends on whats the bottleneck. Do some benchmarks.

Comment: @Spacedman GNU grep does *not* work line-by-line. See the link after "Edit".

Comment: @RolandSmith neat trick. ignore line breaks until you get a match and then check match wrt nearest line breaks. but what it **doesn't** do is read the whole thing into memory and then work on it, which would be the only way that memory utilization could be an issue here.

Comment: @RolandSmith Thanks for this wonderful explanation and also for sharing your observations with an example. It's useful answer and The way you have explained explain makes the people fall in love with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `seek` method of the file handle to rewind from the end of the file, by using a `2` as its second argument. Then you can check for the `abracadabra` string at the end of the file, and if found, scan the whole file (from the beginning) for the `P QRST` string:

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as fh:
    s1 = 'abracadabra'
    fh.seek(-len(s1), 2)
    if fh.read() == s1:
        fh.seek(0)
        for line in fh:
            if 'P QRST' in line:
                print 'Bingo'
```